# How to clear a configuration using config:set command from terminal?

Tags: magento2

you may know that a store configuration value can be set from terminal using this command

`php bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url http://127.0.0.1/magento/`

But today I came accross a situation where I had to reset the value for a configuration or if I say in database terms to set the value of configuration to **null** in core_config_data table.

Does anybody know how is that possible from terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do so by passing an empty string:

```
php bin/magento config:set recaptcha_frontend/type_for/customer_login ""
```

It sets it to `NULL` in the database.

It doesn't work for the path `web/secure/base_url`, though; you'll get a validation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save **NULL** url related configuration from terminal

```
php bin/magento config:set web/secure/base_url NULL
```

If you will run above command then it will give you below error :

> Invalid Secure Base URL. Value must be a URL or one of placeholders: {{base_url}},{{unsecure_base_url}}

This error occured because :

> File : vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Backend/Baseurl.php

```
private function _isFullyQualifiedUrl($value)
{
    return preg_match('/\/$/', $value) && $this->getUrlValidator()->isValid($value, ['http', 'https']);
}
```

Above function check your url should be start with **http** or **https** and end with **/**

If you want to set **NULL** base url then you must be set null value directly from database